# MATE desktop background not redrawing

Tags: mate-desktop

My MATE desktop 1.16.2 has stopped redrawing the background. The effect being that when I move a window, the locations where the desktop background would normally be shown, now shows smeared out samples of the window I am moving.

My desktop background was originally set to show Cosmos slide show, selected from the Appearance Preferences menu.

When I mouse-click right-button on the desktop area, no menu appear. Normally it would show a menu with a `Change Desktop Background` item.

Answer (score 0):

On the top MATE menu bar, select `System` > `About MATE`. You should get a pop-up window showing MATE version number. Press `Close`. Desktop background should now work again, and be black.